# Lock down Windows 7 PCs

Tags: windows-7, lockdown

we're going to be rolling out some laptops with Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit on them to clients and are looking for ways to lock down the majority of Windows settings (version, updates, etc.).

I know SteadyState (free tool from Microsoft) has worked well for many users of XP and Vista, but sadly there's no Windows 7 support.

After some Googling, it looks like Deep Freeze may be an option. Are there any other tools out there that people have used and like? Any other ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Use GPOs (even local ones) to lock it down. [There's tons of info on MS's website](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/bb310732.aspx).

MS also publishes framework documents regarding security practices, for [Windows 7](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=2AB57B5C-8C4F-4B8C-A260-0FE77B5B713F&displaylang=en&displaylang=en).

One you think you've got it locked down a bit, run the [MBSA](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/cc184924.aspx) and it'll generate a report on any glaring errors it finds.

I'd also recommend dumping the Home Edition, get Pro/Ent/Ult (something made for business).

Running gimmicky "we'll plug up all your security holes" software tends to give you the impression that you don't need to think about security practices. While it might tighten up security, users are by far the biggest security problems.

Comment: +1 Also: create users as limited users, not members of Administrators.

Answer (score 4):

Just recently MS released information on how to create a SteadyState like environment in Windows 7, hope this helps someone:
[Group Policy Settings for Creating a Steady State](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=1de3c7ce-5af8-4e54-84b8-1fab6161730f)

[Windows SteadyState Reference Spreadsheet](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=544b466b-558c-4882-8797-c96e5694cb40)

[Creating a Steady State by Using Microsoft Technologies](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=ef232619-7600-4768-b111-f60ba13862ea)

Comment: All but the third link are now dead. Sad.

Comment: @chris - I've updated the links

Answer (score 2):

Another link.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/fdcc/archive/2010/01/15/updated-lgpo-utility-sources.aspx

Answer (score 0):

We use DeepFreeze at the college where I work on all public machines, and it's great. However, it might be a little *too* restrictive for what you want.